# Who killed Fanny the dog and threw the stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunt

In [*Jagten* (*The Hunt*)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106476/), who killed Fanny (the dog) and threw the stone? (Or is it meant to be unresolved?)

There seem to have been two suggestions that it was Theo (and possibly wife who did it):

- After the supermarket fight scene, Theo, wife, and Klara are sitting in their vehicle. Klara asks, "Where's Fanny?" And then the wife looks kinda guilty and shifty and says, "I don't know."
- At the end of the Christmas Eve church mini-fight scene, Lucas tells Theo to leave him alone, which seems to suggest that Lucas suspects Theo of the dog kill + stone throw.

Answer (score 5):

We cannot narrow it down to exactly who killed Fanny, but we could say it's the community or the neighbors who killed the dog because they believe Lucas abused the little kid Klara and wanted him to leave the town.

I understand why you think it's Theo but with the background given about the characters Lucas and Theo in the movie, before the incident, they both are friends since childhood and even their families are close.

From the movie, I felt that Theo did not truly believe that his friend Lucas abused his child but Theo was put in a situation where he has to take his child's side. Remember the church scene, where Theo says to his wife that he thinks Lucas is innocent and he did not do it.